# Bug in 2D Fourier Transform implementation

Tags: matlab, 2d, fft, dft

I am trying to implement a 2D DFT using a combination of 1D DFT in Matlab. When comparing my results against Matlab's inbuilt function (fft2) I realized that I have the following issues:

1. The sign of the imaginary part is being inverted. i.e + changed to - and vice versa.
2. The rows are being ordered in descending order except for the first one.

This image shows the comparison between the two results. The red numbers on the side are there to indicate the reordering issue.

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
x = imread('img.png');
x = double(x);
x = x(1:12,1:5)

% FFT
Xw = complex(zeros(size(x)));
for row = 1:size(x,1)
    Xw(row,:) = fft(x(row,:));
end

for col = 1:size(x,2)
    Xw(:,col) = fft(Xw(:,col)');
end
```

Could someone kindly indicate where my problem is please? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `'` operator is for the **complex** transpose, which means that the matrix is transposed and the **conjugate** of the values is taken. This means that the signs of the complex values are reversed. You don't notice this with real numbers because technically, the imaginary component is zero.

You want to use `.'` instead to preserve the sign of the imaginary component as performing the intermediate FFT per row will result in complex values.  Using just `'` will change the imaginary components of the intermediate results, which will give you the wrong results:

```
for col = 1:size(x,2)
    Xw(:,col) = fft(Xw(:,col).');
end
```

BTW, as a minor note, there is no need to transpose the intermediate columns of your result at all.  If you provide a single vector, `fft` will operate along the first non-singleton dimension, and so using a transpose is superfluous.  It would actually help if you didn't transpose your result at all:

```
for col = 1:size(x,2)
    Xw(:,col) = fft(Xw(:,col));
end
```

Here's an example.  I've generated a random 10 x 10 matrix:

```
rng(123);
x = rand(10);
```

Using your code with correcting the transpose (and without the indexing at the beginning), we get:

```
>> Xw

Xw =

  Columns 1 through 5

  50.1429 + 0.0000i  -0.4266 - 0.2624i   0.8803 + 0.9311i  -0.0526 + 1.7067i   0.7187 + 0.7161i
   0.5066 - 2.4421i   2.7551 - 1.7421i  -1.9994 + 0.6052i   0.2891 + 3.4182i   0.5300 + 2.4417i
   0.1956 + 0.1790i   4.1461 + 1.9648i  -1.3781 - 1.0303i  -0.6872 - 1.0103i  -1.2184 - 0.5783i
  -0.3645 - 1.6193i  -1.8470 - 1.3445i   4.1555 + 0.7432i   2.3707 + 3.8265i  -1.9526 + 1.9464i
  -3.1136 - 0.3704i   2.4132 - 1.0795i  -0.2255 + 1.3062i   0.8436 - 0.5157i  -0.3493 - 0.9994i
  -1.5962 + 0.0000i  -0.3780 - 1.4055i   1.6242 - 0.4842i   0.4457 + 0.4718i  -0.1794 - 2.0014i
  -3.1136 + 0.3704i   0.0134 + 0.1267i   1.0630 + 1.4563i  -0.8864 - 0.3174i  -0.5720 + 1.3041i
  -0.3645 + 1.6193i   0.7028 + 0.2797i   0.1064 + 2.0705i   2.1644 + 0.1685i   0.3095 + 0.7426i
   0.1956 - 0.1790i   2.3511 + 2.1440i   0.7301 - 0.8264i  -1.1974 - 0.3794i  -2.4981 + 1.2363i
   0.5066 + 2.4421i  -3.5897 + 0.7444i   1.2191 - 3.6386i  -2.9659 - 1.6626i  -2.0339 + 0.0880i

  Columns 6 through 10

   2.0373 + 0.0000i   0.7187 - 0.7161i  -0.0526 - 1.7067i   0.8803 - 0.9311i  -0.4266 + 0.2624i
  -1.8782 - 0.9047i  -2.0339 - 0.0880i  -2.9659 + 1.6626i   1.2191 + 3.6386i  -3.5897 - 0.7444i
   2.3752 + 1.8811i  -2.4981 - 1.2363i  -1.1974 + 0.3794i   0.7301 + 0.8264i   2.3511 - 2.1440i
   4.5213 + 0.9237i   0.3095 - 0.7426i   2.1644 - 0.1685i   0.1064 - 2.0705i   0.7028 - 0.2797i
  -1.2259 + 2.1690i  -0.5720 - 1.3041i  -0.8864 + 0.3174i   1.0630 - 1.4563i   0.0134 - 0.1267i
   6.2411 + 0.0000i  -0.1794 + 2.0014i   0.4457 - 0.4718i   1.6242 + 0.4842i  -0.3780 + 1.4055i
  -1.2259 - 2.1690i  -0.3493 + 0.9994i   0.8436 + 0.5157i  -0.2255 - 1.3062i   2.4132 + 1.0795i
   4.5213 - 0.9237i  -1.9526 - 1.9464i   2.3707 - 3.8265i   4.1555 - 0.7432i  -1.8470 + 1.3445i
   2.3752 - 1.8811i  -1.2184 + 0.5783i  -0.6872 + 1.0103i  -1.3781 + 1.0303i   4.1461 - 1.9648i
  -1.8782 + 0.9047i   0.5300 - 2.4417i   0.2891 - 3.4182i  -1.9994 - 0.6052i   2.7551 + 1.7421i
```

I've also verified that this works **without** transposing.  You'll get the same thing as if you were to perform `.'`.  Now, using `fft2`, we get:

```
>> Xw2 = fft2(x)

Xw2 =

  Columns 1 through 5

  50.1429 + 0.0000i  -0.4266 - 0.2624i   0.8803 + 0.9311i  -0.0526 + 1.7067i   0.7187 + 0.7161i
   0.5066 - 2.4421i   2.7551 - 1.7421i  -1.9994 + 0.6052i   0.2891 + 3.4182i   0.5300 + 2.4417i
   0.1956 + 0.1790i   4.1461 + 1.9648i  -1.3781 - 1.0303i  -0.6872 - 1.0103i  -1.2184 - 0.5783i
  -0.3645 - 1.6193i  -1.8470 - 1.3445i   4.1555 + 0.7432i   2.3707 + 3.8265i  -1.9526 + 1.9464i
  -3.1136 - 0.3704i   2.4132 - 1.0795i  -0.2255 + 1.3062i   0.8436 - 0.5157i  -0.3493 - 0.9994i
  -1.5962 + 0.0000i  -0.3780 - 1.4055i   1.6242 - 0.4842i   0.4457 + 0.4718i  -0.1794 - 2.0014i
  -3.1136 + 0.3704i   0.0134 + 0.1267i   1.0630 + 1.4563i  -0.8864 - 0.3174i  -0.5720 + 1.3041i
  -0.3645 + 1.6193i   0.7028 + 0.2797i   0.1064 + 2.0705i   2.1644 + 0.1685i   0.3095 + 0.7426i
   0.1956 - 0.1790i   2.3511 + 2.1440i   0.7301 - 0.8264i  -1.1974 - 0.3794i  -2.4981 + 1.2363i
   0.5066 + 2.4421i  -3.5897 + 0.7444i   1.2191 - 3.6386i  -2.9659 - 1.6626i  -2.0339 + 0.0880i

  Columns 6 through 10

   2.0373 + 0.0000i   0.7187 - 0.7161i  -0.0526 - 1.7067i   0.8803 - 0.9311i  -0.4266 + 0.2624i
  -1.8782 - 0.9047i  -2.0339 - 0.0880i  -2.9659 + 1.6626i   1.2191 + 3.6386i  -3.5897 - 0.7444i
   2.3752 + 1.8811i  -2.4981 - 1.2363i  -1.1974 + 0.3794i   0.7301 + 0.8264i   2.3511 - 2.1440i
   4.5213 + 0.9237i   0.3095 - 0.7426i   2.1644 - 0.1685i   0.1064 - 2.0705i   0.7028 - 0.2797i
  -1.2259 + 2.1690i  -0.5720 - 1.3041i  -0.8864 + 0.3174i   1.0630 - 1.4563i   0.0134 - 0.1267i
   6.2411 + 0.0000i  -0.1794 + 2.0014i   0.4457 - 0.4718i   1.6242 + 0.4842i  -0.3780 + 1.4055i
  -1.2259 - 2.1690i  -0.3493 + 0.9994i   0.8436 + 0.5157i  -0.2255 - 1.3062i   2.4132 + 1.0795i
   4.5213 - 0.9237i  -1.9526 - 1.9464i   2.3707 - 3.8265i   4.1555 - 0.7432i  -1.8470 + 1.3445i
   2.3752 - 1.8811i  -1.2184 + 0.5783i  -0.6872 + 1.0103i  -1.3781 + 1.0303i   4.1461 - 1.9648i
  -1.8782 + 0.9047i   0.5300 - 2.4417i   0.2891 - 3.4182i  -1.9994 - 0.6052i   2.7551 + 1.7421i
```

---

We can show these two are equal by ensuring that all of the element-wise differences between the two matrices is less than a small threshold... say `1e-10`:

```
>> all(abs(Xw(:)-Xw2(:)) <= 1e-10) 

ans =

     1
```

## Take away message

Never use `'` for the transpose.... ever.  [Luis Mendo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2586922/luis-mendo) is a strong advocate of this very fact.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer and your clear explanation. Your solution was correct.

Comment: @ganninu93 My pleasure.  I recognize the error because I did something similar many years ago.  Glad I could help and good luck!

Comment: @ganninu93 I've edited my post.  It turns you out you don't need to transpose your columns at all.

Comment: @ganninu93 hi is there a reason why you unaccepted my answer? Did it not work?

Comment: Thanks so much :) Take care!